# Unable to get users data from facebook using graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making in app in which i show user's hometown,location on profile screen. I get the required data when using developer's account and get data for every user when current user is looking at its own profile.
But when i try to look at other's profile, i don't get the desired data. Here is my code for how i am getting the data out.

```
-(void)loadFbData{
    NSMutableString *graphPath = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"/?id=%@",[self.user valueForKey:@"facebookId"]];
    [graphPath appendString:@"&fields=location,hometown,picture.width(640).length(342),name,gender,email,website"];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:graphPath completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.personalDataView.webLabel.text = [result objectForKey:@"website"];
                self.personalDataView.emailLabel.text = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
                self.personalDataView.webLabel.text = [result valueForKey:@"website"];
               self.profileBasicDataView.livesInLbl.text = [[result objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];
                self.profileBasicDataView.fromLbl.text = [[result objectForKey:@"hometown"] objectForKey:@"name"];
            });
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] valueForKeyPath:@"data.url"]];
            [self.profileBasicDataView loadUserFbData:result];
            [self.profileImage loadImage:url];
        }
    }];
}
```

**website and email is hidden when other user's profile is shown.

Comment: Reading this data requires the user to give your app permission to access it first, so you can not get it for just any random user.

Comment: @cBroe permissions are granted to app, if permissions weren't granted - the user wouldn't be able to see location and hometown while visiting its own profile.

Comment: He's saying that the users you are querying for that are not the current user must also authorize your application and grant it permission to read their profile.

Comment: Yes i got his point - the user i am querying has also authorized my app against the following permissions "user_about_me", "user_hometown", "user_location". 
where "user_location" and "user_hometown" are used if current user is looking at its own profile, while "user_about_me" is used when others are looking at its profile.

Comment: still not getting data

Comment: You need to use a user access token for the user whose profile you're requesting.

Comment: Can you post some code demonstrating how to get user's access token and get data accordingly?